# How to convert mySQL subquery into HQL name query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, subquery, hql, graphql

This is query is perfectly working on with mySQl but it is not working with hql name query any one can help me it is grateful

this is my SQL

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM EsEvent  ORDER BY eventTimestamp DESC ) e WHERE isReset=1 GROUP BY eventId;
```

this is my HQL name query which i wrote.

```
FROM ( FROM EsEvent es ORDER BY es.eventTimestamp DESC ) EsEvent e WHERE e.isReset=1 GROUP BY e.eventId
```

but this is not working it will and up with an error

> Failed to create sessionFactory object: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: HQL_GET_ALL_ESEVENT_GROUP_BY_EVENT_ID_ORDER_BY_EVENT_TIMESTAMP_AND_RESET_ID_ONE

my purpose is before i evaluate the where clause i need order it any one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in HQL:

```
SELECT e FROM 
(SELECT es FROM EsEvent es ORDER BY es.eventTimestamp DESC ) EsEvent e
WHERE e.isReset=1 GROUP BY e.eventId
```

But a simple way is:

```
SELECT es FROM EsEvent es 
WHERE es.isReset=1
GROUP BY es.eventId
ORDER BY es.eventTimestamp DESC
```

**Pay attention:**

Normally, when you use a `GROUP BY` clause in your field list you must use only grouped fields or aggregate (by function) fields

Comment: still same error. i just need to fulfill my purpose if there are any alternative ways i can try with that.

Comment: @randikaisuru Try to put SELECT e.eventId and tell me if your query works

Comment: still same error. but this is perfectly work "SELECT e.eventId FROM EsEvent e WHERE e.isReset=1 GROUP BY e.eventId" but when it's added subquery part it will end with an error.

Comment: @randikaisuru Two things: the first select field list and group by field list must be the same. The second, the subquery is unusefull. But if you want to use you must change it. Tell me if for you is important so we can try to change it

Comment: my main purpose is before i evaluate the where clause i need order it and on that ordered list i need to select  where e.isReset=1 list. i don't need to use subquery. if there is a another way i will accept it.

Comment: @randikaisuru Ok, if you use GROUP BY e.eventId you can't use ORDER BY e.eventTimestamp because this field not present in group by clause. But if you grouped by id you have the same rows if you don't use group by (id I suppose is your primary key). So you can remove group by

Comment: OK, I have remove group by now my hql query is like this "SELECT e.eventId FROM (SELECT es FROM EsEvent es ORDER BY es.eventTimestamp DESC ) EsEvent e WHERE e.isReset=1" but still getting same error.

Comment: Without subquery:SELECT es FROM EsEvent es 
WHERE es.isReset=1
ORDER BY es.eventTimestamp DESC

Comment: this is Ok, but is this grantee the my primary purpose?

Comment: Yes about number of rows. Tell me you about the informations